# Anime about these girls that fly cold war jets and fight against aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, anime

This anime is about these girls that fly Cold War era jets, fighting against aliens that have stolen all of the world's advanced tech.

It was only the pilot episode put out, but for the life of me I can't remember what it is called, and when I try Googling it I find things like *Yukikaze*, and *Girly Air Force*.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you watch this anime, and when do you think it was made?

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags/aviation

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [*Shiribako*](https://shirobako.fandom.com/wiki/SHIROBAKO), or more specifically the in-universe anime being produced by the studio portrayed, known as [*Third Aerial Girls Squad*](https://shirobako.fandom.com/wiki/Third_Aerial_Girls_Squad) (Daisan Hikou Shoujyotai)?

> Four years ago, the enigmatic Builders appeared on Earth, creating
> mysterious structures known as Pillars, which now cover one-third of
> the world's surface, and copying technology for their own use before
> permanently disabling the real devices. The only aircraft that remain
> operational are those from the 1970s and before.

Comment: For the record, those are not suitable outfits in which to fly a fighter jet.

Comment: The wiki alludes to this, but this isn't a standalone series. SHIROBAKO is an anime about creating anime, and Third Girls Aerial Squad is one of their productions in-universe. An actual first episode of this series was released, I believe as a DVD special, but nothing else.

Comment: @qazmlpok - See edit. Better?

Comment: @Valorum When has women's fashion in anime *ever* made sense?  Unless of course you take their fashion sense as a character's proclamation of "I'm so self assured that I'll wear what ever I want, regardless of the consequences"

Comment: @PeterM - Well, if nothing else, the flightsuits seen in the show are impractical from a fire-safety perspective, lack pockets to hold items and wouldn't provide a warm working environment. The cockpit of the McDonnel-Douglas F-4 was, for example,  notoriously cold.